# Как посмотреть информацию о виртуальной памяти?

Tags: delphi

Правильно смотрю информацию о виртуальной памяти ?

```
Status.dwLength := sizeof(TMemoryStatusEx);      
GlobalMemoryStatusEx(Status);
      AddToLog('Memory ' + IntToStr(Status.dwMemoryLoad) + '%');
      AddToLog('Общий объём виртуальной памяти ' + IntToStr(Status.ullTotalVirtual div 1024417) + 'МБ');
      AddToLog('Количество свободной виртуальной памяти ' + IntToStr(Status.ullAvailVirtual div 1024417) + 'МБ');
```

Comment: А то данные постоянно разные. И сильно сомневаюсь в точности.

Answer (score 1):

Вот код популярного [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4024494/11619532) с enSO, использующий `GlobalMemoryStatusEx`. Можно сравнить результаты. Я вижу у вас не происходит обнуление структуры `FillChar(MemStatus, SizeOf(MemStatus), 0);`.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  Classes,
  SysUtils;

type
  DWORDLONG = UInt64;

  PMemoryStatusEx = ^TMemoryStatusEx;
  TMemoryStatusEx = packed record
    dwLength: DWORD;
    dwMemoryLoad: DWORD;
    ullTotalPhys: DWORDLONG;
    ullAvailPhys: DWORDLONG;
    ullTotalPageFile: DWORDLONG;
    ullAvailPageFile: DWORDLONG;
    ullTotalVirtual: DWORDLONG;
    ullAvailVirtual: DWORDLONG;
    ullAvailExtendedVirtual: DWORDLONG;
  end;

function GlobalMemoryStatusEx(var lpBuffer: TMemoryStatusEx): BOOL; stdcall; external kernel32;

procedure Main;
var
  MemStatus: TMemoryStatusEx;
begin
  // initialize the structure
  FillChar(MemStatus, SizeOf(MemStatus), 0);
  MemStatus.dwLength := SizeOf(MemStatus);
  // check return code for errors
  Win32Check(GlobalMemoryStatusEx(MemStatus));

  Writeln(Format('dwLength: %d', [MemStatus.dwLength]));
  Writeln(Format('dwMemoryLoad: %d', [MemStatus.dwMemoryLoad]));
  Writeln(Format('ullTotalPhys: %d', [MemStatus.ullTotalPhys]));
  Writeln(Format('ullAvailPhys: %d', [MemStatus.ullAvailPhys]));
  Writeln(Format('ullTotalPageFile: %d', [MemStatus.ullTotalPageFile]));
  Writeln(Format('ullAvailPageFile: %d', [MemStatus.ullAvailPageFile]));
  Writeln(Format('ullTotalVirtual: %d', [MemStatus.ullTotalVirtual]));
  Writeln(Format('ullAvailVirtual: %d', [MemStatus.ullAvailVirtual]));
  Writeln(Format('ullAvailExtendedVirtual: %d', [MemStatus.ullAvailExtendedVirtual]));
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      ExitCode := 1;
      Writeln(Format('[%s] %s', [E.ClassName, E.Message]));
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 0):

Если кому нужно то сделал вот так

```
var 
  Status: TMemoryStatusEx;
begin
      FillChar(Status, SizeOf(Status), 0);
      Status.dwLength := sizeof(TMemoryStatusEx);
      Win32Check(GlobalMemoryStatusEx(Status));
      Тут идет запись в лог
      AddToLog('Количество оставшейся физической памяти при ' + IntToStr(Status.ullAvailPhys div 1024417) + 'МБ' + #13);
      AddToLog('Количество свободной виртуальной памяти при ' + IntToStr(Status.ullAvailVirtual div 1024417) + 'МБ' + #13);
```

Comment: Почему `div 1024417` ?

Comment: Чем это отличается от моего ответа? Зачем писать свой ответ и не принимать верный?